# Animate progress on 100s of UIButtons without blocking main thread

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` with at most a few hundred cells (not all visible at once). Each cell contains a `UIButton` with a way to indicate progress of an upload. A `URLSession` performs the uploads in background tasks.

Currently, the session delegate is the `UIViewController` that manages the cells. As a result, the session calls delegate
`.URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:` to periodically inform the delegate of the progress of sending content to the server.

In the delegate method, I find the `UIButton` associated with this task and animate the new progress (I can find the button because I make `button.identifier = task.identifier`).

This approach forces me to find the button every time the delegate method is called. This seems indirect and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this — there could be 100s of buttons so worried about runtime.

I was thinking to make the button be the session delegate, but that goes against MVC and the button reference may disappear or change in a table view causing undefined behavior (though it sort of makes sense to only update buttons that are actually in memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there could be 100s of buttons

No, there couldn't. Cells that do not appear on the screen do not exist at all (because cells are reused in a table view). So you only need to worry about the cells that are actually visible at any one moment. See UITableView `visibleCells` and `indexPathsForVisibleRows`. Thus, even though your approach is not extremely efficient, it isn't extremely inefficient either.

However, the *correct* way to do this is to use the `progress` object vended by your upload task. When the upload starts, tell the cell or the button or whatever to start observing the `progress` object's `fractionCompleted` using key-value observing. Now the cell or the button or whatever is in direct contact with that one task and can update itself every time it hears that the `fractionCompleted` has changed. When the cell stops being displayed, stop observing. There's a little more to it (i.e. to cope with reused cells that scroll onto the screen when the corresponding task is already in progress) but that's the basic architecture you want.

Comment: I can imagine where there could be 100s of buttons on screen (or where you'd want to update 100s of views), but I get what you're saying. Thanks!

Comment: Right, but the point is, even if there are 10000 buttons the way I'm describing is completely efficient.